# What material might a truly sentient A.I. brain be made of?

Tags: artificial-neuron, artificial-consciousness, brain

I read that silicon may not be able to be create a robot brain that actually thinks because of its inability to process enough. Some people say nanomagents could generate low energy A.I. but I was wondering. What might truly conscious A.I. brains be built from in 200 years?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. The terms "truly conscious" or "truly sentient" (even if you remove "truly") are quite arbitrary.
2. Let's assume that the AI will resemble something that we call a computer today (so we'll not consider biological AIs here).

With these two points we could try to answer your question as if was "What will the fastest computers made of in 200 years?".

Since predicting how the world would look like in 200 years is something we have no idea how to do, I'll make another step and change the question to:

**What materials future computers could me made of?**

Here are some arbitrarily chosen examples with links to articles about computers made of them:

1. silicon - what we have now,
2. [complex oxide materials](https://www.ornl.gov/news/complex-materials-can-self-organize-circuits-may-form-basis-multifunction-chips)
3. [carbon nanotubes](https://www.technologyreview.com/2021/10/27/1036819/dna-computing-spintromics-history/)
4. [superconductors](https://uwaterloo.ca/institute-for-quantum-computing/quantum-101/quantum-information-science-and-technology/quantum-materials)
5. [manganese silicon](https://phys.org/news/2021-12-materials-quantum-technologies.html) (it's an alloy - mixture of chemical elements - made of silicon, iron, manganese, carbon and more)
   This material is magnetic and I think this or something similar is what the article you read called *nano-magnets*.
   This is candidate material for quantum computers so it's seems that the article you read made the assumption that AI will be a quantum computer - something that may or may not be true.
6. something very different - the future is unknown.